# Upload file/image flickering drag and drop in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to create a simple system to drag and drop some files.
I've did good, but sometime when you are with your cursor near `.drop` div margin and enter, it's starts "flickering".

After you drag a image (.png) for example in the `blue background` everythings works (even when you leave it) ...but... sometimes with your cursor on the margin of `.drop` div, something is happening.

How can I fix that?

Code: https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-field-empq1r

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are dragging on the `.chatMessage` and out of the `.drop` element, you don't have any issue but when you are going on the `.drop` element it's another children element and **has itself events**.

So you shouldn't have any issues if you prevent events from the children's elements.

**Solution**

Add this CSS code to your CSS file:

```css
.dropContainer * {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Is working. I've also added `onDrop={(e) => handleDrop(e)}` to `.chatMessage` in order for the handleDrop to work.

Answer (score 0):

Make these changes in css

```
.drop {
  /* margin: 30px; */
  height: calc(100% - 60px);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: white;
}

.drop::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  inset: 30px;
  outline: 3px dotted grey;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).